# Relationship between over-fitting, gradient vanishing, and local minimum?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm trying to learn Deep learning.

I'm so confused about these problems: Over-fitting, Gradient vanishing and Local Minimum.

So far, I understood about the RBM which do pre-training because of Over-fitting. But some people saying that pre-training is needed because of Gradient Vanishing, and some other people said because of Local Minima.

So.. question is that, which one is true? If all people saying is correct, could you please tell me about the relationship between those concepts?

---

I’m still confusing. As so far, what I have understand about Gradient Vanishing is that early layers couldn’t training well due to reaching the gradient zero. So what you mean is that early layers that are not training well are same concept as struck at the local minimum? If so, what all layers are well-trained is global optimum. Am I right?

Secondly, in the case of pre-training, I’ve known that it is no longer spotlighted by receiving a lot of data and randomly initialized weights. And receiving a lot of data is related to preventing over-fitting. So..  in this perspective was developed due to preventing over-fitting. Is it wrong idea?

Comment: This is a very broad question. There is plenty of information available online about these topics. You can also read the [deep learning book](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is so helpful to master the core concepts of machine learning (specially statistical machine learning), statistics and probability theory, before digging into Deep learning algorithms. I suggest [the Elements of statistical learning](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/148009.The_Elements_of_Statistical_Learning) and [Probability Theory](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/151848.Probability_Theory) books.

As far as I know, RBM pre-training is used as a preprocessing in training CNNs, which is a feed-forward network, trained by back-propagation delta rule. Generally speaking, back-propagation is performed on feed-forward networks because we want the gradient of error (defined over the difference between the real and predicted output) to reach zero, which is what you call **gradient vanishing**.

Now one problem is that gradient of error reaches to zero on a **local minimum**; and our progress would stall there because our weight correction steps are proportional to the magnitude of gradient (which is near zero on a minimum, local or global). there are techniques to avoid this, like 'random weight initiation'.

**Over-fitting** is totally a different story. it is a statistical phenomenon which indicates that your algorithm has almost "memorized" training data instead of "learning" them (training error is much smaller than your test error). not only neural networks, but also every machine learning algorithm (as a data-driven statistical model) has the risk of being over-fitted to your data, when the degree of freedom of your model (number of adjustable parameters i.e. weights in neural networks) is much higher compared to the size of your training set. suppose you have 1 point in a 2D-space you can fit countless lines and curves to that point. So there is no guarantee that the selected model also fits an unseen test instance which occurs after the model is selected.

Now, the problem with a CNN, is that the number of layers and neurons are so high that it takes like forever to reach the zero gradient(each neural connection is supposed to be a weight). you can test this idea by gradually increasing the size of a Neural network and measure the training time. So **gradient vanishing** would be a practical problem here. Now RBM here is a technique that efficiently adjusts your initial weights, so that you start your back-propagation process when the initial weights are meaningfully close to their final desired value. think of it as a head start. So as an answer to your question, my vote goes to gradient vanishing problem.

Again I should say that the other two problems are still there, when working with CNNs. But as far as I know, they require their own solutions: "a large dataset and regularization techniques" for over-fitting and "carefully study the behavior of gradient changes and random weight initiation" for getting trapped in local minima.

Comment: I guess I kind of didn't get your new questions right... but as far as I understood, let me note these comments:
-  in a normal back-propagation technique (not RBM), all of the connections are updated simultaneously. there is no difference between an early and a late layer.
- random weight init technique is still used and is not outdated
- deep learning "ALWAYS" requires a large set of data. that is why you always hear "big data" besides "deep learning" Google Deep Mind lab papers is a great source of getting to know this interesting duo

Comment: btw please ask new questions as a comment on my reply. so that your post would be readable for other people too, while the order of questions and answers would be more traceable

Comment: I understand gradient vanishing question differently. In my opinion he ask about vanishing error signal in backward propagation. Standard error backpropagation apply on classical sigmoidal units have problems with train more than two hidden layers. Error signal from output has lower and lower values so firsts layers aren't trained. RBM pre-training set weights values based on data-neuron interaction. After this pre-trainning you have "reasonably" initialized weights and BP may be applied.

Comment: @viceriel Yes I guess you're right about gradient vanishing... Great comment, thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Forgive me for being late. I have been busy for a while, so recently I was able to see again the questions I registered before. Thanks for the great comments.

Answer (score 1):

**Over-Fitting:** Over-fitting is all about the difference of accuracy between training and test data. If difference is big then either you have to increase the size of data set (data augmentation) or use regularization technique. Over-fitting indicates that your model has memorized training data not generalize on training data.

**Gradient Vanishing:** Gradient Vanishing is difficulty which occurs because of activation functions with small range. For example, if you are  using sigmoid activation function, then inputs to each layer even with larger values will fall in the range of [0,1]. What does it mean? It means if you change parameters with larger value, it will not cause big change in output as it will again fall within [0,1]. So the rate of change of output with respect to parameter will be too small. As a result, no parameter update will occur means vanishing gradient will occur.

**Local Minimum:** Local minimum is a point where model gets stuck because of small learning rate. This issue can be resolve by using large learning rate or different optimizer like rmsprop, Adam etc.

Answer (score 0):

So about local minimum. Task of training algorithm is minimize error function. Most used is 
1/2(desired - reached)^2

For obtaining this, backprop use first derivation of this function for obtaining minimization. BP compute gradient of error based on weights and gradient is direction of most increase error. So BP used -gradient what is opposite of most increase of error.

So where is problem? This method not guarantee global minimum. Global minimum is weights configuration which produce the smallest possible error.

Also overfitting. Imagine hundreds dimension input vector and millions weights. Theoretically is network able memorize every input value from your dataset and classified it. But if you get network something from test dataset, network with high probability fails. You want network generalize not memorize. For avoiding this can be used dropout(in learning process you drop some synapse or neuron) and validation dataset. You train network with training dataset and error decrease, but you also observe error on your validation dataset(but network isn't learning from this data). So error on both dataset decrease, but if error decrese on training data and start increase on validation you stop learning because this situation is overfitting symptom.